# how to find a word in url column in a given object

Tags: soql, sosl

I am looking for SOQL/SOSL to find records in object having a URL column with some filter(text in column( on URL column, tries like and sosl, both doesn't work. Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to query a URL type field in an object for records containing a specific word in the URL field?

If that is the requirement please try below code,

```
String yourInputWord;
yourInputWord = '%'+yourinputWord+'%';

//Then query using like clause,
[select id,url__c from object__c where url__c like :yourInputWord];
```

Comment: I was trying for LinkURL column of FeedItem, just saw its not fitlerable..:(